# Is it possible to simulate a display when ssh-ing into a google cloud instance?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Say I choose an ubuntu instance with google cloud and ssh into it through terminal. Is google simulating a display in the background or just giving me access to the virtual machine's terminal?

What would happen if i tried to take a screenshot through ssh? What about if i used something like pynput to move the mouse? Would these commands register like it does on my ordinary computer? If I would like it to, what do i need to do?

Im new to ssh and google cloud but for instance *selenium*, a browser simulator that can navigate webpages, requires additional software to work in ssh.

Answer (score 0):

The default linux images provided by google do not offer a desktop by default, Screenshoting and mouse movement would not work. However you can run headless tools likes Chrome's Puppeteer to render screenshots of webpages.

If you're willing to put in some time configuring the instances you can install desktops and remotely connect to them. For example a [guide here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/linux-gui-on-the-google-cloud-platform-800719ab27c5). Do keep in mind if you run a desktop environment you'll likely need a larger instance than the tiny micro instances.

Comment: I have read your guide and it uses a VNC server which displays the screen and relays my mouse presses and commands to the virtual server. It sort of does what i want, but is there any more lite weight? i only need to interact with terminal and my programs will do all the mouse navigating and testing so i don't really need to see the screen while im doing it. I only need it to be there for screenshots and mouse movements to work. This is important to me because i will be doing this with several instances at once.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Running ubuntu-desktop will create a desktop instance?